# Run a Colaboratory script from Gsites & extract graphs

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, google-sites

For a AI project validation, I need to do a web app to present the first version of my script.
This script is build on google collaboratory as it read live data on gsheet.

Due to all constraint (security and other) I would like to use gsite to run the colab script.
Is it possible to embed the script into a gsite page? I would need that the users doesn't see any code but be able to change hyperparameters, and get graph results.